# Js: CanvasJS.Chart how use with loop

Tags: javascript, laravel, charts

My code working buy only for the last index i mean last i. 
how fix to by show for i = 0,1,2 ... dl in my graph

```
<script>
var mar = [' <?php App\twojedzialki::sumupraw(); ?> '];
var dl = (mar["length"] / 2) - 1;
var i;

window.onload = function() {
    for (i = 0; i <= dl; i++) {
        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {

            title: {
                text: "Obecna Uprawa"
            },
            data: [{
                type: "pie",
                startAngle: 25,
                toolTipContent: "<b>{label}</b>: {y} ha",
                showInLegend: "true",
                legendText: "{label}",
                indexLabelFontSize: 16,
                indexLabel: "{label} - {y} ha",
                dataPoints: [
                    { y: mar[2 * i + 1], label: mar[i] }
                ]
            }]
        });
    }

    chart.render();

}
</script>
```

for not working as I want, in function chart I can't put my function bcs is the error.

Comment: I think the problem might be, you're always using  `chartContainer` to display the canvas, and on each iteration you're redrawing on top of the previous drawing.

Comment: yeah but i cant put for inside chartContainer. so how fix it

Comment: Use different div and id for every chart, like in the example here: https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/how-to/render-multiple-charts-in-a-page/ . Then just iterate and use a different id every time

Comment: not work this .